# VBA Filter the selection

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim data_text As String
data_text = Analiza_Date.TextBox6.Value

Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Activate
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

I want to filter only the selection of column "A3" .

VBA mark with yellow color the last row:

```
Range(Selection).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

Comment: A3 isnt a column, its a cell.  Do you mean that you want the filter to be applied so that only the item matching the current selection in column A is shown in the list?  Not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: @smackenzie, the issue was in `Range(Selection)`.  While `Range("A3").Select` actually select a single cell `Range` but the subsequent `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` selects a multiple cells `Range` from cell "A3" down to _some_ cell in the same column (the _some_ depending on the "emptiness" of the cell below and actual presence of empty cells below the first selected one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim data_text As String
data_text = Analiza_Date.TextBox6.Value
Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Activate
Range("a3").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

Always rework what's generated by the Recorder. It's a great tool to learn and to find out what instructon is required for a specific task, but the generated code is a mess and should always be cleaned uop.

Answer (score 2):

you have to change:

```
Range(Selection).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

into either:

```
Range(Selection.Address).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

or, better:

```
Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=data_text
```

even better is you:

- avoid `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` patterns since they lead to loose control over what `Range` (in what `Worsheet` and of what `Workbook`) you're actually dealing with, especially in multiple worksheets/workbooks contexts
- work with `Range` variables set with fully qualified (up  to worksheet at least) references, like follows:

  ```
  Dim data_text As String

  data_text = Analiza_Date.TextBox6.value
  With Worksheets("PE_Centralizare") '<--| refer wanted worksheet
      .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:=data_text '<--| all those leading "dots" mean their subsequent object refer to the object in the last 'With' statement (i.e. "PE_Centralizare" worksheet)
  End With
  ```